# Getting "expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]" in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, sentinel

I am working on Kibana 6x and using SentiNL to generate email alerts. Below is my query to generate mail if my application generate log "CREDENTIALS ARE NOT DEFINED FOR PULL EVENT SOURCES" with threshold 1. When i play my watcher i get below error.

Error: `Watchers: play watcher : execute watcher : execute advanced watcher : get elasticsearch payload : search : [parsing_exception] [match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME], with { line=1 & col=80 }`

Query:

```
"input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "index": [
          "filebeat-2019.03.21"
        ],
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "msg": "CREDENTIALS ARE NOT DEFINED FOR PULL EVENT SOURCES"
            },
            "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
            "bool": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": "now-15m/m",
                    "lte": "now/m",
                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
            "dateAgg": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "time_zone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
                "interval": "1m",
                "min_doc_count": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Also I have used "minimum_number_should_match" to track threshold value. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution(Here i have not added threshold value) :

```
{
"actions": {
    "email_html_alarm_2daee075-0f24-408e-a362-59172b5e3a1d": {
        "name": "email html alarm",
        "throttle_period": "1m",
        "email_html": {
            "stateless": false,
            "subject": "Error v1.9 conditon",
            "priority": "high",
            "html": "<p>{{payload.hits.hits}} test hits Hi {{watcher.username}}</p>\n<p>There are {{payload.hits.total}} results found by the watcher <i>{{watcher.title}}</i>.</p>\n\n<div style=\"color:grey;\">\n  <hr />\n  <p>This watcher sends alerts based on the following criteria:</p>\n  <ul><li>{{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.queryType}} of {{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.over.type}} over the last {{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.last.n}} {{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.last.unit}} {{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.threshold.direction}} {{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.threshold.n}} in index {{watcher.wizard.chart_query_params.index}}</li></ul>\n</div>",
            "to": "abc@qwe.com",
            "from": "abc@qwe.com"
        }
    }
},
"input": {
    "search": {
        "request": {
            "index": [
                "file-2019.04.03"
            ],
            "body": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "CREDENTIALS ARE NOT FOUND",
                                "analyze_wildcard": true,
                                "default_field": "*"
                            }
                        },
                        "filter": [{
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "gte": "now-1d",
                                    "lte": "now/m",
                                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"condition": {
    "script": {
        "script": "payload.hits.total > 0"
    }
},
"trigger": {
    "schedule": {
        "later": "every 2 minutes"
    }
},
"disable": true,
"report": false,
"title": "watcher_title",
"save_payload": false,
"spy": false,
"impersonate": false
```

}